# get an integer -unit digit in a simple way

Tags: objective-c

i am not sure about my english, but i need to get the unit digit of an integer.
WITHOUT complex algorithm but with some API or another trick.

for example :

```
int a= 53;
int b=76;
```

this i add because i almost always dont "meet the quality standards" to post! its drive me crazy! please , fix it ! it took me 10 shoots to post this,and other issue also.

i need to get `a=3` and `b=6` in a simple smart way.

same about the other digit.

thanks a lot .

Comment: @vladimir why -1 ? this is a fact that many times you just cant post here because some strange algorithm. sometimes adding a "?" solve it , or adding one more word. instead of -1 me , fix that, because many of my friends got this .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here is how to split the number into parts

```
int unitDigit = a % 10; //is 3
int tens= (a - unitDigit)/10; //is 53-3=50 /10 =5
```

Comment: ..God said.. ;) ;)   (TL;DR: "how to divine the number")

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING**

> here is how to divine the number into parts
>
> ```
> int unitDigit = a % 10; //is 3
> int tens= (a - unitDigit)/10; //is 53-3=50 /10 =5
> ```

this answer is totally incorrect. It may work only in a number of cases. For example try to get the first digit of 503 via this way

It seems the simplest answer (but not very good in performance):

```
int a = ...;
int digit = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", a] substringToIndex:1] intValue]; //or use substringWithRange to get ANY digit
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for % operator.

```
a=a%10;//divides 'a' by 10, assigns remainder to 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code "gets" the digits of a given number and counts how many of them divide the number exactly.

```
int findDigits(long long N){
    int count = 0;
    long long newN = N;

    while(newN) // kinda like a right shift
    {
        int div = newN % 10;
        if (div != 0)
             if (N % div == 0) count++;
        newN = newN / 10;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is answering the question that was asked...i.e. getting the least significant digit of the number.

Comment: "i need to get a=3 and b=6 in a simple smart way.

same about the other digit." The question is not only about the least significant digit, isn't it?

Comment: The original question is certainly confusing, maybe he does want more digits.  But in any event, your function returns a "count", which isn't what was asked for.