# C language Program change number if greater then 9

Tags: c

I'm working on a program using C language and when the user inputted data comes up I need to use `number*2` but if the number goes over 9 I want to use only the ten digit. 
I've tried using an if else statement but it didn't work.

The whole purpose is to pull only the tenth place digit if the number is greater than 9; if not, just take the number itself.

Example:

```
    int second = (CardNumber/10)%10; //user inputted number
   if (number*2 > 9){number*2/10)%10} else {number*2} //trying to use an if statement 
    int sumOther = second; //assigning the number to a new variable
```

ps. that's not what my code looks like i'm just trying to give a visual view.

Comment: You said not what your code looks like but just wanted to let you know number *= 2; number*2 does nothing if you didn't already

Comment: re. “That's not what my code looks like” - well, why don't you show us what your actual code looks like…

Comment: Since the code you show doesn't assign anything in the if/else, nothing changes.  Maybe you meant to assign to `second`?  It isn't clear.  Show the real code if you want help with it.  We're good at guessing where you've gone wrong, but ultimately, people are more inventive than we can imagine.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your code correctly, you want your user `number*2`, but only grab the unit digit?

If so, it's easy!

```
(number*2)%10 //if number*2 < 9, it's number
```

If your number*2 is < 9, %10 will simply return the number.
Else, it will return the unit digit.
See [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971438/get-an-integer-unit-digit-in-a-simple-way)

I hope I understood it well!

EDIT:

```
if(number >4)
{
   answer = number*0.2; //This effectively divides by 5 (or divides (number*2) by 10
}
else
{
   answer = number*2;
}
```

Hope that's what you're looking for. :)

Comment: Oh, indeed! I'll edit my answer with a solution for that too.

Comment: Yes Arkku that's it that's what I want to do.

Comment: Thank you guys so much I have been working all day with problems after problems thank you for helping and it was so quick and i was hard to understand but you guys are awesome have a good one.

Comment: Anytime! Please try to express your problem clearer next time! :-P

Comment: Note: `if(number*2 >9)` is like `if(number > 9/2)` or `if(number > 4)`.  `answer = (number*2)/10` is like `answer = number/5` which does not overflow.